# R using decimals as indexing numbers

Tags: r, indexing, decimal

R documentation says:

Indices are numeric or character vectors or empty (missing) or NULL. Numeric values are coerced to integer as by as.integer (and hence truncated towards zero).

For example, if you have:

```
vector<-c(10,20,30,40,50)
```

and ask for the position 2 of this vector, you will  have:

```
vector[2];
20
```

But, you can have the same result you if you ask for the index 2.5

```
vector[2.5];
20
```

This is a very odd behaviour. This is a dangerous behaviour for my purposes. Is there an option to force R to return an error when you have a decimal value as an array or vector index?

Comment: in your code, you can check the index value before subsetting and throw an error if the value is not integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to define a vector class with the described behavior:

```
as.myvector <- function(x){
    class(x) <- c("myvector", class(x))
    x
}

`[.myvector` <- function(x, condition) {
    if(any(condition != as.integer(condition)))
        stop("Invalid index")
    class(x) <- class(x)[2]
    x[condition]
}

v <- as.myvector(c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50))

v[2]
## [1] 20
v[2.5]
## Error in `[.myvector`(v, 2.5) (from #2) : Invalid index
v[2:5]
## [1] 20 30 40 50
v[c(1.1,2:4)]
## Error in `[.myvector`(v, c(1.1, 2:4)) (from #2) : Invalid index
```

Comment: Interesting! Thanks!